# Loading multiple files and concatenate: ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

After checking Stack Overflow, I reviewed the path directory—and it works fine as shown in "Loading files".

However, when I try to concatenate I get the above ValueError as shown in "Concatenate files".

What can I learn from this?

Also, is it ideal to use the below line of code?

`files_names=os.listdir()`

Loading files:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

files_names=os.listdir()
def load_all_csv(files_names):
    # Follow this function template: take a list of file names and return one dataframe
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    return files_names

print(files_names)
all_data=load_all_csv(files_names)
all_data
```

Concatenate files:

```
combined_data=[]
for filename in all_data:
    if filename.endswith('csv'):
        #print("All csv files: ", filename)
        df=pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='Month')
        combined_data.append(df)
all_data=pd.concat(combined_data, axis=1)
all_data
```

Comment: Can you please add the code examples into your question, instead of screenshots? Do you know what `continue` does in your code? Please find out what it really means and does.

Comment: @SandervandenOord continue is used in loops until the required condition is achieved. It does not fit in the code I'm writing. Understood. Thank you for the push.